# Which css properties allow 'auto' as a value?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to implement a polyfill in IE<9 for computed style. I've figured out how to deal with converting em, pt, and % to px but I need a solution for auto.

I need a list of properties that allow auto so I can figure out how to handle properties with 'auto' as a value.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html

Comment: Thanks, Add that as an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: the answer of elclanrs is good too(maybe better, a more complete list), you may accept this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was kind of a lazy question I'd say. I found this [list](http://meiert.com/en/indices/css-properties/) on google in 2 sec.

```
align-self
alignment-adjust
background-size
bottom
break-after
break-before
break-inside
clip
color-profile
column-count
column-width
crop
cursor
dominant-baseline
drop-initial-size
flex-basis
font-kerning
grid-column
grid-column-sizing
grid-row
grid-row-sizing
height
icon
image-orientation
image-rendering
left
line-break
marker-offset
nav-down
nav-index
nav-left
nav-right
nav-up
overflow-style
page
page-break-after
page-break-before
page-break-inside
play-during
rendering-intent
right
size
speak
table-layout
text-height
text-justify
text-underline-position
top
width
z-index
```